# How to copy a disk drive over network to another computer (create and use such disk image)?

Tags: networking, disk-image

I originally have thought, that I would just use `scp` to copy my laptop disk drive onto server array for backup purposes.

---

As it turned out, it may not be possible (`not a regular file`), or I just might have missed some workaround, anyway, the question is quite broad, so to narrow it as tight as possible, let me re-phrase it:

---

How to copy the whole NVMe drive from the laptop from a live Linux Mint 19 USB stick onto my server running a RAID-1 array and save it there to a file?

---

Local source:

```
/dev/nvme0n1
```

Remote destination on `192.168.0.1xx`, port `59xxx`:

```
/mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feel free to add your answer, and if better I'll accept it for future readers to have the best one marked.

---

First of, I connected the laptop to the same router as there is the server, into a 1Gbit network full-duplex. And I temporarily enabled SSH password access to the server.

---

Second, I created a USB stick with Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon, booted it up, unmounted the automatically mounted NVMe disk partition - don't know if I clicked on it, or if it did the system itself - having 32GB of memory, I decided to update all packages, and installed `pv` in order to see a progress bar and ETA of the copy procedure.

---

And the command as a final solution to the problem is:

```
pv /dev/nvme0n1 | ssh root@192.168.0.1xx -p 59xxx "dd bs=100M of=/mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img"
```

---

Resulting output (without the password prompt):

```
476GiB 1:21:23 [ 100MiB/s] [=============================>] 100%
0+15643397 records in
0+15643397 records out
512110190592 bytes (512 GB, 477 GiB) copied, 4885.02 s, 105 MB/s
```

Job done.

---

Inspired by [Archemar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79818/archemar)'s comment:

> Have you tried to mount the remote image? Just imagine you need to recover only some files from a particular directory.

Indeed, for new users this might pose a problem, so to have this answer 100% complete, I better include it.

So. How do we mount that whole disk image's main partition?

Well, first you want to list its partitions in general:

```
fdisk -l /mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img
```

It will output something similar to this:

```
Disk /mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 989573D5-37E7-437A-B680-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Device                                                             Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img1   2048     194559     192512    94M EFI System
/mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img2 194560 1000214527 1000019968 476,9G Linux filesystem
```

You then mount it as a loop device (it's implicit nowadays, but for you to know about it, I explicitly added the `loop` option) while using offset option (note: AFAIK, only `root` can use options) computed as the (logical) Sector size multiplied by the Start sector of a partition you are about to mount). Like this:

```
mount -o loop,offset=$(( 512 * 194560 )) /mnt/raid1_3tb/laptop-dell--ssd-nvme-toshiba--linux-mint-19--2019-dec-19.img /mnt/someMountPoint
```